# Up navigation to a parent activity from different sub-activities

Tags: android, android-intent, back-stack

In my app, each activity has the same menu in the action bar, which provides access to the parameters activity.

When I am in the parameters activity, I would like to get to my parent activity by clicking on the left-orriented arrow like in my other activities.

The unique parent of others activities is defined in manifest.xml.

But for the parameters it's impossible as it has multiple parents:

- mother > child > parameters is possible
- mother > parameters is also possible!

We can find this comportment in the gmail app:

- main > parameters, in which you can get back to main
- main > email > parameters, in which you can get back to the specific email you were looking at.

So my question is how to get this gmail comportment? Can we change dynamically the parent activity of parameters?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in which you can accomplish this:

1. Use a [`TaskStackBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html) and specify the parent chain in the manifest using `android:parentActivityName` and the associated support-v4 meta-data tag [as described in the corresponding *Providing Up Navigation* training](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#SpecifyParent). This is the recommended method as it obeys the hierarchical task stack.
2. Provide some extra into the launch intent and navigate up depending on that custom flag. Note that launching activities through this mechanism will not show the back animation of the current activity closing.

Comment: I already used this method for my others activities, I can go back and forward between my activities such as :  
  
    A > B > C then A > B then A > B > D for example  

Because I defined in manifest that :
B parent of A
C parent of B
D parent of B

But, my parameters activity can be accessed from every activity, so it has multiple parent, I cant define it in the manifest.xml as you recommand and as I did for other activities, do you get it ?

Comment: I'd suggest for such a case to specify a different back stack [as detailed here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp).

Answer (score 0):

Comments mess up well indented answer so I anwser my question :

I finally ended up with a simple custom code,
because I had already visited a few times your link (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp) and it didnt helped me much.

Here's what I did : 
(in the `else` of http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#BuildBackStack)

```
// particular case  
// if this activity is the Parameter/Help activity, just finish it   

if(this.getClass().equals(ActivityParametre.class) || this.getClass().equals(ActivityAide.class)){  
    finish();  
    return true;  
 }  
// general case  
// otherwise, use pre defined code  
else {  
    NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);  
}
```